# Can I use the Soap API to get Escalation Rule Info?

Tags: escalation

I want to get Escalation Rule Info with Soap API,
but in Soap API have no EscalationRule class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escalation Rules info cannot be fetched through SOAP API.

Thanks,
Vipul